# Show a form on all worksheets in an Excel file

Tags: excel, user-interface, vba

I am writing a little generator script (using Excel VBA) to generate a bunch of source code, given various input from users.

Currently I have one 'generator control' worksheet that provides access to the generation scripting tools.  Here there is a button that pops up a little form with various generation options.

Each portion of source code also gets its own worksheet for generation purposes.  So, I essentially have one worksheet for generation commands and perhaps 10-20 that are for source code parameters.

What I would like to do is somehow take my popup form and embed it within each other worksheet...make it 'always visible' in the corner or something like that.

Each source code worksheet is generated programmatically as well...I'd assume that I could replicate my popup button for each worksheet, but I'd rather have this form always visible.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than putting it on the worksheet, could you not have a toolbar button that simply pops up a dialog? (In other words, your user interface is a UserForm rather than a set of worksheet controls).

Comment: yep, this is probably the best option...thanks for the suggestion!